# How to use a url sent from js, in a php data grid

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, url

I have a js function that returns the url of an api that I need to use in a data grid. This api will show the students assigned to a teacher, and this datagrid has to change according to the user (teacher who started the session), and this function is the one that returns the api that the json gives me for each teacher

```
**function newdatagrid(){
  SESION_USUARIO = obtenerUsuarioSesion();
  var usuario = SESION_USUARIO;
  console.log('El usuario es: ', usuario);
  var url = url1 + '/apis/alumnosasignados/' + usuario;
  console.log( url);
  return url;
}**
```

what I don't know is how to send this ur to my php file which is where the datagrid is. (which now has a static url for testing).

```
**<table class="easyui-datagrid" id="dgper3" nowrap="false" data-options="
       iconCls: 'icon-edit',
       singleSelect: true,
       required:true,
       method: 'get',
       url: http://localhost/apis/alumnosasignados/24'
    ">
    <thead>
    <tr>
            <th
                data-options="
                field:'id',
                onDblClick:openWinPermisoLaboralter,
                align:'center'"
                width="5%">Id</th>
            <th
                data-options="
                field:'nombre_completo',
                onDblClick:openWinPermisoLaboralter,
                align:'center'"
                width="30%">Nombre completo</th>
            <th
                data-options="
                field:'estado',
                onDblClick:openWinPermisoLaboralter,
                align:'center'"
                width="8%">Estado</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>**
```

the json returns

```
**[
    {
        "id": 66,
        "nombre_completo": "Ingrid López",
        "estado": "INSCRITO"
    },
    {
        "id": 67,
        "nombre_completo": "Elmer Martinez",
        "estado": "INSCRITO"
}]**
```

I have tried to send the url in this way, but it appends it to another url that is not functional.

```
**<script type="text/javascript">
function javascript_to_php() {
    var url = newdatagrid();
    console.log( url);
    window.location.href = "myphpfile.php?name=" + url;
}
</script>
 
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">' , 'javascript_to_php();' , '</script>';
// comprobar si tenemos los parametros w1 y w2 en la URL
if (isset($_GET["name"])) {
    // asignar w1 y w2 a dos variables
    $phpVar1 = $_GET["name"];
    // mostrar $phpVar1 y $phpVar2
    echo "<p>Parameters: " . $phpVar1 . "</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>No parameters</p>";
}
?>**
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, in my php code I only left a table but no function

```
<table id="dgper3"></table>
```

And in javascript program the following function

```
<?php
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">' , 'newdatagrid();' , '</script>';
?>
```

And in javascript program the following function

```
function newdatagrid(){
    SESION_USUARIO = obtenerUsuarioSesion();
    var usuario = SESION_USUARIO;
    console.log('El usuario es: ', usuario);


    var ourl = 'http://localhost/apis/alumnosasignados/' + usuario;

    console.log( ourl);
  
        $('#dgper3').datagrid({
          singleSelect: true,
          required:true,
          method: 'get',
          url:ourl,
          columns:[[
              {field:'id',title:'ID',width:'5%',align:'center'},
              {field:'nombre_completo',title:'Fecha',width:'44%',align:'center'},
              {field:'estado',title:'Descripcion',width:'15%',align:'center'},
          ]]
      });
        return ourl;
  }
```